# IPv6: Cannot reach outside of LAN (OpenWrt Router connected to ISP Router through Wi-Fi)

Tags: router, dhcp, ipv6, openwrt

Hello dear server expert, I would like to ask for you help for my installation.

I have a Freebox Revolution (I am French and my ISP is Free).
The box provides IPv4 and IPv6. Every computer connected to it from ethernet or Wi-Fi get a IPv4 and IPv6 without any problem. It is wonderful...
Now, I have two servers without Wi-Fi capabilities.
They need to be connected by ethernet.
The problem is that it is not possible.
I can't put them next to the box and a long cable is not an option.
So, I came up with a solution that is working for IPv4 but not for IPv6:
I have a TPLink TL-WR841N v7.1 and I flashed it with OpenWrt.
I updated it recently with Barrier Breaker.

The TPLink connects to the Freebox through Wi-Fi and get an IPv4 in the `192.168.0.0/24` network and provides addresses in the `192.168.1.0/24` network to its connected servers.

So, there is two IPv4 networks and that's working. My Servers can go on the internet.

Now, I would like them to be reachable from internet and for that purpose, I would like to set up IPv6.

The freebox has an option "prefix next hop" that I set to the IPv6 address that my router gets from the freebox.

And here is my `/etc/config/network`file on the OpenWrt router:

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config interface 'lan'
    option ifname 'eth0'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '64'
    option ip6prefix 'XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX::/64'

config interface 'wan'
    option ifname 'eth1'
    option proto 'dhcp'
    option type 'bridge'

config switch
    option reset '1'
    option enable_vlan '1'
    option name 'switch0'

config switch_vlan
    option vlan '1'
    option ports '0 1 2 3 4'
    option device 'switch0'

config interface 'MyWiFiSSID'
    option proto 'dhcp'

config interface 'MyWiFiSSID6'
    option ifname '@MyWiFiSSID'
    option proto 'dhcpv6'
```

My servers obtain IPv6 addresses with the right prefix but they can't ping outside and they are not reachable from outside.

What am I missing ?

Thank you!